# Where is this converging to on $y=x$?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, graphing-functions, problem-solving, symmetric-polynomials

Well I was playing with graphs and I started plotting equations as the following:

> $$\underbrace{x+y}_{degree=1}=1 \tag{1}$$
>
> $$\underbrace{x^2+y^2+xy}_{degree=2}+\underbrace{x+y}_{degree=1}=1 \tag{2}$$
>
> $$\underbrace{x^3+y^3+x^2y+xy^2}_{degree=3}+\underbrace{x^2+y^2+xy}_{degree=2}+\underbrace{x+y}_{degree=1}=1 \tag{3}$$
>
> $$\underbrace{x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4}_{degree=4}+\underbrace{x^3+y^3+x^2y+xy^2}_{degree=3}+\underbrace{x^2+y^2+xy}_{degree=2}+\underbrace{x+y}_{degree=1}=1 \tag{4}$$

*and so on ...*

---

And here are the plots : (*Click on them to get a better pic*)

**Zoom:1**

[image: 1]

**Zoom:2**

[image: 2]

**Zoom:3**

[image: 3]

---

*It seems like these graphs are converging to some value on the (red dashed line) $y=x$.*

> ***What is this value?***

---

**My Attempt:**

Since the graphs are converging to $y=x$, hence we solve the two equations as :

(*Let's take degree 2*)

$$\Rightarrow x^2+y^2+xy+x+y=1 \space\space\space and \space\space\space y=x$$

$$\Rightarrow x^2+x^2+x^2+x+x=1$$

$$\Rightarrow 3x^2+2x=1$$

Hence if we take $degree=n$:

> The equation becomes : $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n=1$

---

1. **Am I right?**
2. **How do you solve this?**
3. **Any more comments on this question?**
4. **How to represent equations $(1),(2),(3),(4),\cdots$ in a more general way?**

---

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28from%20n%20%3D%201%20to%20infinity%29%20%28n%2B1%29x%5E%28n%29%20%3D%201%20) showed that when [solved](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20for%20x%20%3A%20-%28%28x-2%29%20x%29%2F%28x-1%29%5E2%20%3D%201%20) (IDK how?) $x=1\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and via plotting it looks like $x=1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

How?

---

***Thanks!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of the both sides of that equation as functions of $x$, you're looking for a value $x$ with 
$$
f(x) = g(x)
$$
where $f$ is a sum and $g$ is a constant function. 
The sum happens to also be 
$$
F'(x)
$$
where 
\begin{align}
F(x) 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+1}\\
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{n}\\
&= -1-x + \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}\\
&= -1-x + \frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align} 
where this last step is from the geometric series formula. 
Hence 
$$
F'(x) = -1 + \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
$$
Setting this to $1$, we get
\begin{align}
1 &=  -1 + \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
2 &= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
2(1-x)^2 &= 1
(1-x)^2 &= \frac{1}{2}\\
1-x &= \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
-x &= -1 + \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
x &= 1 + \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}

Pretty nifty!

A partial answer to question 4:

Suppose you add a new variable, $z$, and include in your formulas enough copies of $z$ in each term to make the terms all have the same degree. So you get

\begin{align}
F_1 (x, y, z) &= x + y\\
F_2(x,y, z) &= x^2 + xy + y^2 + xz + yz \\
F_3(x, y, z) &= x^3 + x^2y + xy^2 + y^3 + x^2z + xyz + y^2 z + xz^2 + yz^2
\ldots
\end{align}
Then each $F_k$ is almost a sum of every $k$th power monomial in the three variables: 
\begin{align}
G_1 (x, y, z) &= x + y + z\\
G_2(x,y, z) &= x^2 + xy + y^2 + xz + yz + z^2 \\
G_3(x, y, z) &= x^3 + x^2y + xy^2 + y^3 + x^2z + xyz + y^2 z + xz^2 + yz^2 + z^3
\ldots
\end{align}
the only difference being the addition of the $z, z^2, z^3$ at the end of each one.

The equations you're solving are
\begin{align}
F_1 (x, y, z) &= 1\\
F_2(x,y, z) &= 1 \\
F_3(x, y, z) &= 1\\
\ldots
\end{align}
which I propose to rewrite as 
\begin{align}
G_1 (x, y, z) &= 0 \text{ and } z = 1\\
G_2(x,y, z) &= 0 \text{ and } z = 1\\
G_3(x, y, z) &= 0 \text{ and } z = 1\\
\ldots
\end{align}
which shows that the things you've drawn are the $z = 1$ slices of certain very symmetric surfaces in 3-space, ones defined (for $k$) as the 0-level sets of the sum of all homogeneous symmetric monomials of total degree $k$.

Is that the kind of "general" statement you were looking for?

BTW: cool question!

Comment: From the plot I got $x$ as $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ only. Why is this? And can you please solve Question 4?? And THANKS!!

Comment: Look in the lower left corner of your plot -- the other side of each "blob". The curves are converging there, too, and they're converging to $1 + 1/\sqrt{2}$, I'll bet. I can't solve question 4 because it seems to me that you've described your curves just fine, by writing out polynomials for them.

Comment: uhhh...No . The general form i was looking for was ... may be in the form of summation or something ... in terms of $n$ where $n$ represents degree. So if I put $n=3$ I get equation 3 and like that.

Comment: To the downvoter : Why the downvote though?

Comment: @NeilRoy  BONUS QUESTION:  What curve is the equation converging to?

Comment: @JerryGuern Good question ... You know the answer? Well my guesses will be ... For even degree it forms a closed shape but for an odd degree it takes a curved continuous line. So at $\infty$, we can say that the degree value $n$ *oscillates* between odd and even and hence **I** can't say.

Comment: @JerryGuern BTW can you answer ... my question? (Comment #3 here)

Comment: See the last 5 paragraphs for an answer (sort of) to question 4. It may not be what you're looking for, but it's an answer very much in the spirit of algebraic geometry, which is the field in which questions like this generally reside.

Comment: @JohnHughes I guess the general form is $\sum\limits_{m=1}^{N} \big(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m} x^n+y^{m-n}\big)$ where $N$ is the degree.

Comment: @JohnHughes BTW as Jerry said : can we guess what's gonna be the plot at $n=\infty$?

Comment: @NeilRoy  The downvote?  I don't know.  I upvoted this.

Comment: Your guess is almost right: you need to change the "+" to a "$\times$". As for guessing what happens as $n \to \infty$, your function and $(x+y)^n$ end up differing by a whole bunch of terms of order less than $n$, which, for large $x$ and $y$, turn out to therefore be insignificant. For odd $n$, I think that this means that your curve will tend towards curves that have $x+y = const$ as an asymptote. For even $n$, I think that the limit might end up looking diamond-shaped...but that'd take more work than I'm willing to spend. :)

Comment: @NeilRoy  Curse you, you totally nerd-sniped me with this question.

Comment: @JohnHughes  I'm sitting around today injured and bored, so I actually ground the damned limiting behavior of curve at degree infinity.  I got: (1-2x-2y+2xy)=0 where |x|<1 and |y|<1.  This cure does intersect x=y=(1-1/Sqrt(2)).   I got this by using 1+z+z^2+...+z^m = (1-z^(m+1)/(1-z) a whole bunch of times.  Ordinarily I have a life, but today I have back spasms, so here I am.

Comment: OK, cool. Thanks!